# How to create Pass type signing certificate?

Tags: ios6, passbook

I want to access passbook feature of iOS 6. For that I need to create and distribute pass. This process requires pass type identifier and signing certificates.

How can I get it using my developer account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just there with new tab, "Pass Type IDs".
I should have check developer portal bit more.

Comment: clicking on Pass Type IDs is not going to the corresponding tab.

Comment: the link is wrong over there. Identified by trail and error https://developer.apple.com/ios/my/passtypeids/index.action

Comment: I've written a [detailed guide](http://support.passdock.com/kb/guides/create-and-export-a-certificate)

Comment: @MacTeo I passed through same cycle month ago.. but I have not prepared a doc.. thanks for the guide..